# how to use regular expression to match content between two tags

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

I tried this code

```
"<h2 class="a-text-normal">.*</h2>"
```

but it will match the whole sentences not just the content.

```
<h2 class="a-text-normal">The info to be matched</h2>
```

Comment: I just wanna match the text "The info to be matched"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a non greedy quantifier and also regex lookarounds.

```
(?<=<h2 class="a-text-normal">).*?(?=</h2>)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU4hZ9/1)**

Code

```
NSString *orgStr = @"<h2 class=\"a-text-normal\">The info to be matched</h2>";

NSString *URLRegExPattern = @"(?<=<h2 class=\"a-text-normal\">).*?(?=<\/h2>)";
NSError *regExErr;
NSRegularExpression *URLRegEx = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:URLRegExPattern 
                                                                          options:0
                                                                            error:&regExErr];

NSString *URLString = nil;

NSRange range = [URLRegEx rangeOfFirstMatchInString:orgStr 
                                            options:0 
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, orgStr.length)];

if (!NSEqualRanges(range, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
    URLString = [orgStr substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
}

NSLog(@"URL: %@", URLString);
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple (*for generic languages*) regex would be:

```
[^>]+(?=<)
```

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/mZ2qP2/1)

Hope it helps.

**EDIT:**
If your language allows you to use `>\K` or `(?<=>)` in the begin of the regex it will increase speed when searching.